# Method execution order sorting in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, annotations

I've been stuck at this problem for a long time now and couldn't find help anywhere else on web, so this might prove useful to someone else later.

I have a list of words and every word in list has it's own two arrays of words it should go before and after.

Here's an example:

```
"forest" - before:{"tree"}
"frog" - after:{"mushroom"}
"mushroom"
"leaf" - after:{"mushroom"}, before: {"frog"}
"tree" - before:{"mushroom"}
```

These words should be ordered in following order: forest, tree, mushroom, leaf, frog. So basically, "after" doesn't mean that a word needs to go right after another one (neither does "before"), it just can't go before said word (or after in "before" case).

I tried solving this problem by using array lists and adding elements at custom indices, that breaks as soon as an element like "leaf" is inserted (element that goes between two other elements).

This example has been simplified so it doesn't confuse anyone, I'm actually writing a mod loader that sorts methods whose annotation says which mods they should execute after/before.

EDIT:
I managed to solve the problem by turning before into after on elements contained in before arrays.

After that, all I did was iterate over all elements and then check if that element was executed already (You'll see why in a second), if it wasn't executed, execute all after elements first in the same manner and then execute the actual element. I also do some checking to prevent cycles and such.

Comment: Can you post some code you tried? Any tell what problems you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write code for you, but I'll outline some hints on the algorithm.

The first thing to realise is that there's no point in the `after` information, because saying that `B` comes after `A` is the same as saying `A` comes before `B`. Start by replacing all the `after` information with equivalent `before` information.

Next, you have to realise that if an item is in one of the `before` arrays, it cannot go first. So you have to do is look through all the `before` arrays to find an element in none of them. If there is an element in none of those arrays, that element can go first. (If not, the problem is impossible).

Once you've decided which element goes first, discard its `before` array and complete the list using recursion.

Comment: After turning all before blocks into after blocks, it was a pretty simple problem to solve. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms) problem.

The names of methods can be treated as nodes in the graph, and your 'before' and 'after' relationships are directed edges in said graph.